# SPLimitedWebPartManager.Dispose() vs SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web.Dispose()

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, object-model, dispose

`SPLimitedWebPartManager` references `SPWeb` object internally and implements `IDisposable` interface, therefore we need to dispose it explicitly.

As I understand, we need to dispose its internal SPweb object like this: `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web.Dispose();` But I also see some code in many places where it calling dispose method directly on `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Dispose();`
So, whats the difference on calling between  `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web.Dispose();` vs `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Dispose();`

Fof example this code, how i dispose ?

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = item.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
try
   {
                foreach (var wp in mgr.WebParts)
                {
// i do some stuff here
                }
    }
catch { }
            finally
            {
               mgr.Dispose();// for disposing, this should be used
               mgr.Web.Dispose();// OR this ?
            }
```

Disposechecker has following comments for this line `mgr.Dispose();`

Dispose Explicitly Called on SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web
     mgr.{Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager}Dispose()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web.Dispose()` will dispose of the `SPWeb` object used by `SPLimitedWebPartManager` while calling `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Dispose()` would dispose the `SPLimitedWebPartManager` itself.

Keep in mind that you should never dispose of objects you haven't created yourself! `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web` is created by another object called `WebPartManager`. Doing `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web.Dispose()` is something similar to dividing by zero :)

Here is an example:

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = item.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared));
{
    foreach (var wp in mgr.WebParts)
    {
        //try-catch exceptions here if needed
        // i do some stuff here
    }
}
```

which basically compiles to:

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = item.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
try
{
    foreach (var wp in mgr.WebParts)
    {
        // i do some stuff here
    }
}
catch { }
finally
{
   mgr.Dispose();// for disposing, this should be used
}
```

Do not call `mgr.Web.Dispose();` as this object will be disposed automatically by `SPLimitedWebPartManager` (or maybe `WebPartManager`).

Comment: I have edited my question by adding some code, let me know your thoughts how i dispose that?

Comment: Thanks!! That means if i use SPLimitedWebPartManager within Using Directive, then I don't need to call Dispose method explicitly, right?

Comment: That is exactly the point of "using" :)